# Activity trigger more than once if using launchMode="singleInstance

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a activity which i declare as launchMode="singleInstance in Manifest file. and using blow code to starting this activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockScreenActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

To close this activity i am doing like:   `finishAffinity();`
But some how when i finish this activity i can see another open activity instance of this. Can someone tell me how i can finish all OR only create a single one when i need to start this activity from different places inside my application?

Comment: Try using  `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: I already used this, but still can see 2 instances. Is there any way from which i can finish all instances of same activity in android ?

Comment: Post your activity code